# How to get a link to a Store app in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

When looking at a details page in the *Store* metro app, how can I get a link to this page so I can send it to someone else?

The only way I found right now is to [google the application name with site:apps.microsoft.com parameter](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20store%20remote%20desktop%20app%20site:apps.microsoft.com) and make sure it's the same application by looking at the title, publisher, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On opening the Store, select the app u wish to share. Open the Charms menu and click on Share to obtain a link to the app, which you can share via Email.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, the Charms bar, I'm still not used to it.